# how to pass the javascript variable to textbox?

Tags: javascript

i would like to ask a question.

how can i pass the javascript generated code to the textbox "code" ?

I surf the internet but I cannot find the answer

I hope all of you can help me.

thanks!!

```
  <form><input name="code" type="text" value="" >
                <script>
                    function makeid()
                    {
                        var text = "";
                        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

                        for( var i=0; i < 6; i++ )
                            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

                        alert(text);
                        return text;
                    }       
                </script>
                  <input type="button" style="font-size:9pt" value="Generate Code" onclick="makeid()">
                  </input></form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the value of the text box, rather than returning the value

The updated code,

```
var codeElem = document.getElementById('code');

function makeid() {
  var text = "", possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", i = 0;

  for( ; i < 6; i++ ) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }

  //alert(text);

  codeElem.value = text;
}​
```

You've to add an `id` attribute to the text box, so that it can be accessed easily.

```
<input id="code" name="code" type="text" value="" >
```

Working [example](http://jsbin.com/eyefu6)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set that textbox's `value` value. If its `id` was `code`, you could just do this:

```
document.getElementById('code').value = text;
```

But as it stands, you'll have to cycle through *all* inputs to look for it:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    i = inputs.length;

while (i) {
    i -= 1;
    if (inputs[i].name === 'code') {
        inputs[i].value = text;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need not iterate over all input elements in a form, as you can use `getElementsByName` to get the textbox with a name property. So your second example can be rewritten as `var codeElem = document.getElementsByName('code')[0]` to get the single textbox as shown in the question.

Comment: @Livingston I was thinking, as I wrote that, "There's a better way. There's got to be." @Javed The `===` makes sure to compare the actual values. For example, `0 === "0"` is false, even though `0 == "0"` is true.

Answer (score 0):

The following code change for the two input fields will cause the random string to appear in the input text field, in addition to the alert box:

```
<input name="code" id="code" type="text" value="" >
<!-- original javascript code goes here-->
<input type="button" style="font-size:9pt" value="Generate Code" 
    onclick="document.getElementById('code').value = makeid()">
```